# Using discrete random variable as index in JAGS

Tags: bayesian, jags, stan

I have a model that can be distilled into,

$$d \sim U(1,20)$$
$$Y_t \sim N(X_{t-d},\sigma^2)$$

for two time series that have observations from $Y_{1,..,t}$ and $X_{1,...,t}$.

I'm trying to code it up in jags to handle the discrete parameter but the problem is that I can't figure out how to write the for loop for observations on $Y_t$, since the likelihood can only involve $Y_{d,...,T}$ I want to write something like

```
for (t in d:T){
   y[t]  ~ dnorm(x[t-d],1)
}
```

However, this obviously fails since jags needs d to be a number. Is there a mask routine in jags that can account for this? Any thoughts? Should I try marginalizing out the discrete parameter? I have trouble thinking about what that means for d.